# Why can't I add write permissions to this file?

Tags: permissions, homebrew

I'm running Homebrew 0.9.5 under OS X Mavericks. My ultimate goal is to compile the source code for a program (not available through Homebrew) which depends on `pkg-config`. After installing Homebrew I ran `brew install pkg-config`, got a "brew link error", and ran `brew link --overwrite pkg-config`. This gave me a different error: `Error: Could not symlink share/doc/pkg-config/pkg-config-guide.html /usr/local/share/doc/pkg-config is not writable.` I can't seem to get past this error. Running `sudo chmod 666 /usr/local/share/doc/pkg-config` does not change the file permissions from `-rw-r--r--`. Similarly I came across a similar question on this site where the issue was fixed by doing `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local`; but this didn't work either in my case. Why am I not able to add write permissions to this file?

### More details

I originally thought it would be no big deal to compile `pkg-config` on my own, but when I tried doing so I found myself in a maze of dependencies: `pkg-config` requires (and is required by) `glib`, which requires `gettext` and `libffi`. When I tried to compile `gettext` I was able to run `make` and `make install` but got several errors and "...not found" messages in the process. Nonetheless it seemed to be installed correctly. Once I got `gettext` and `libffi` installed, I tried to do `./configure glib` and got an error related to `gettext`. At that point I gave up and installed homebrew. After installation I got messages advising I remove some files, and did so. I also got this: `Warning: Some directories in /usr/local/share/locale aren't writable. ... You should probably`chown`them`. I did that as well. Then I tried to install `pkg-config` and ran into the problem described above.

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message the directory with permissions issue is `/usr/local/share/doc/pkg-config`, but you claim to have run `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local` which changes ownership of `/usr/local` directory only, not affecting any sub-directories. You should run

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/share/doc/pkg-config
```

and see how that goes. If it doesn't help, please add the output of `ls -l /usr/local/share/doc/pkg-config` to your post to make it clear what's going on.

As a side note, it's perfectly normal for sub-directories of `/usr` to be owned by root and not be writable by regular users. Rather than changing the permissions / ownership, you should run commands writing in these directories as root, e.g.

```
sudo brew install pkg-config
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you installed pkg-config before.
You may uninstall and reinstall it.

brew uninstall pkg-config